# Main window in WPF application is not showing in screen share in skype or teams

Tags: c#, wpf, screen, share

When I join a meeting on skype or teams I need to share the content of the application main window (without any other thing on the screen), but it's not showing in the window share menu, I can only stream it with the whole desktop.

[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr55f.jpg)

But, when I open Login window it appears in the window share menu while the main window still do not appear ! As in the image below.

[Login window appears in the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtQKg.jpg)

Does anyone have any idea what would prevent the window from appearing in the window share menu ?

Comment: I think this is a fair question. Why don't you look into the decisive difference between your main window and login window?

Comment: I already did a lot, and couldn't find the deffirence, I'm not the one who created the original code, so I'm not able to figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I figured out that the window needs a Title so it is selectable in Teams for sharing.
Once I added the Title to my main window everything works.

It can be done in the code:

```
   mainWindow.Title = "test";
```

or in XAML:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Height="900" Width="1200" MinWidth="900"
        x:Name="mainWindow"
        Title="{x:Static p:Resource.MainView_Header}">
...
</Window>
```

Comment: Sadly I no longer have access to the code, but i agree with your answer, we didn't use Title in views, Thank you !!